# get values as string from firebase data snapshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to simply get values of the key as a string and use them
But the firebase snapshot always returns key/value pair.

[image: data structured]

```
else if (message.content === `${prefix}save`) {
    writeUserData(message.author.id, message.author.username);
    message.channel.send('Data written successful!');
    firebase.database().ref('users').child(message.author.id).get()
    .then ((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
            //console.log(data.key);
            console.log(data.val);
        });
    });
    message.channel.send('User data is: ');
}
```

I want to get value of username (`kha333n` as in this) and use it in `message.channel.send('User data is: ');`

console logs

```
   Debugger attached.
VU Bot Loaded!
644787932519071744
```

on using the key.

```
PS C:\VU-Bot> node .\index.js
Debugger attached.
VU Bot Loaded!
{ username: 'kha333n' }
username
```

returned when used with new reference...   (updated code above)

```
 PS C:\VU-Bot> node .\index.js
    Debugger attached.
    VU Bot Loaded!
    { username: 'kha333n' }
    [Function (anonymous)]
```

returned when val is used instead of key.

Comment: `key` is a property, not a function. So `data.key`.

Comment: I have tried all the methods given in docs.

Comment: I have no idea what to do with that Usman. All I can see is the code you shared and the corresponding error message, In that case (as also pointed out in the error message) you're trying to call a `key()` function on a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key), but that class only has a `key` property. If you call it as `data.key` (without `()`) this error will disappear.

Comment: Question updated...

Answer (score 3):

Unlike `key`, which is a property, `val()` is actually a function, so needs to be called with parentheses `()`.

So to log the key and the value of the snapshot:

```
firebase.database().ref('users').child(message.author.id).get()
.then ((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        console.log(data.key);
        console.log(data.val());
    });
});
```

---

If you only want to get the username of the user, that can be more easily accomplished with:

```
firebase.database().ref('users').child(message.author.id).child('username').get()
.then ((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Here you don't need a loop, as we're already loading just the one property we're interested in.